# Location of settings file for deploying static files with Django on Apache2 with mod_wsgi

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am trying to follow the tutorial on [Deploying static files on Apache using mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files) from the  1.6 Documentation. I already have a work in progress site deployed on Apache using mod_wsgi but I need to learn how to correctly deploy static files instead of linking to external Bootstrap CSS as I have been doing.

My issue is I have no idea where the below sample settings from the documentation is or where it should go.

[Below is the relevant DjangoProject text](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files)

> If, however, you have no option but to serve media files on the same
>   Apache VirtualHost as Django, you can set up Apache to serve some URLs
>   as static media, and others using the mod_wsgi interface to Django.
>
> This example sets up Django at the site root, but explicitly serves
>   robots.txt, favicon.ico, any CSS file, and anything in the /static/
>   and /media/ URL space as a static file. All other URLs will be served
>   using mod_wsgi:

It then gives the below sample code which I will need to modify

```
Alias /robots.txt /path/to/mysite.com/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/mysite.com/static/favicon.ico

AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /path/to/mysite.com/static/styles/$1

Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Followed by some clarification instruction

> If you are using a version of Apache older than 2.4, replace Require
>   all granted with Allow from all and also add the line Order deny,allow
>   above it.

There are some similarities to my below `<VirtualHost>` file. Should I just add it to this? Or should it be stored in another location?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment
ServerAlias phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie
WSGIScriptAlias /bias_experiment/ /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi

Alias /static/ /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/static/
<Location "/static/">
    Options -Indexes
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is supposed to go in the same place as your virtualhost configuration.